# instanceof not working on references while loading images with AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, image, reference, android-asynctask

I had a deep look at the documentation here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html and I used this guide http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html to create a ImageLoader which handle concurrency with AsynchTasks.

My code is almost the same and in particular I have the code below that is pretty identical:

```
private static BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    if (imageView != null) {
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof DownloadedDrawable) {
            DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = (DownloadedDrawable)drawable;
            return downloadedDrawable.getBitmapDownloaderTask();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that the condition

> drawable instanceof DownloadedDrawable

is never verified. Everything looks good but the `drawable` seems not to be an instance of my `DownloadedDrawable` class and I don't know why. Can you help me?

**EDIT**: I've found that this is related to references. Indeed, `imageView.getDrawable()` returns an object which has a BitmapDrawable reference

```
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@yyyyyyyy
```

If I try to cast it to a DownloadedDrawable object (instance of my customized subclass) or to use the instanceof operator on it, I have an error because the object is accessed with a DowanloadedDrawable reference

```
my_package.image_loader.DownloadedDrawable@xxxxxxxx
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Is drawable non-null?

Comment: yes it is. I have checked every reference and everything seems well allocated.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to skip reinventing the wheel for image downloading. There are great open source libraries that handle simple downloads and make it really easy for you to manage disk and memory caching.

I've worked on [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) myself but there is also [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and a few others you should try.

Both libraries will handle `AdapterView` recycling for you and perform a ton of other tasks.